Almost everywhere property
Let $(X,\mathcal{M},\mu)$ a measurable space, $\mu:\mathcal{M}\to [0,+\infty]$ a positive measure and consider $f:X\to [0,+\infty]$ a measurable function.
Theorem. If $E\in \mathcal{M}$ and $\int_E f\ d\mu=0$, then $f(x)=0$ a.e. $x\in E$.
My attempt to proof:
Let $A=\{x\in E, \hspace{3pt} | \hspace{3pt} f(x)\ne 0\}=\{x\in E, \hspace{3pt} | \hspace{3pt} f(x)> 0\}$ and we want to prove that $\mu(A)=0$.
First, $A=f^{-1}\left((0,+\infty)\right)$ and so $A\in \mathcal{M}$.
If $\mu(E)=0$, then the thesis follows from $A\subseteq E \Longrightarrow \mu(A)\leq \mu(E)=0$.
Let's suppose that $\mu(E)>0$.
In this case we can consider that for every $x\in A$, we have $0<f(x)$ and so $0<\int_A f\ d\mu$.
This is sufficient because:
$$0<\int_A f d\mu\leq \int_E f d \mu =0$$ since $A\subseteq E$.
So $\mu(A)=0$ is necessary.
Does my proof make sense? Is there something to write better?

In this case... $0<\int_Af$. That's wrong... $A$ may be of measure $0$ (in fact it is...)

Let $A_n:=\{f\geq \frac{1}{n}\}$. Define
$$A:=\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb N}A_n=\{f>0\}.$$
Using MCT yields $$0=\int_E f\,\mathrm d \mu\geq \int_A f\,\mathrm d \mu=\lim_{n\to \infty }\int_{A_n}f\,\mathrm d \mu\geq \frac{1}{n}\mu(A_n),$$
and thus $\mu(A_n)=0$ for all $n$. Therefore, by the continuity of the measure, $$\mu(A)=\lim_{n\to \infty }\mu(A_n)=0.$$ Therefore $f=0$ a.e. as wished.

You surely know that this is a duplicate, don't you?

@geetha290krm : There is indeed probably an answer of this question on MSE... and so ? I didn't find it immediatly, so I answered. All my excuses for that, and thank you for reminding me that I made something wrong that doesn't match with your policy. But if you find a good link, then I'll erase my answer since it doesn't seems to suit you that someone can answer to a question that may already exist on MSE ;-) Again all my excuse, I won't do it again.
